# PrestaShop custom filters

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, prestashop

Before I use only joomla, so sorry if my question is silly.
I liked [this](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/45063.html)(templatemonster.com) template, and want create site on it. The question is: Can I add fiters by "century", "material{silver, broze, gold), county{Uk, Germany...} and so on at that place. If this is not possible, then what it would cost of order similar module \ fix in template design
[image: module position]

Answer (score 0):

yes you can set everything in features. and now you have to use the "Layered navigation block" module. in that module you will have option to filter the products by features.